# iTerm up arrow autocomplete

Tags: bash, iterm

Recently, the up-arrow to scroll in my bash history in iTerm 2 stopped functioning as it did before.  In the past, if I started typing a command (let's say, `curl') and then pressed up, it would only cycle through my bash history that matched that prefix (similar to pressing C-r).  Anyone have any idea why this might have been unset and/or how I set this back to the default?

Comment: I don't think iTerm has anything to do with that.

Comment: This rather sounds like zsh functionality

Answer (score 2):

To invoke similar functionality in iTerm2 you will need to use the `CMD+;` shortcut.

Comment: Because obviously changing the shortcut to something unintuitive is the thing to do :p